# How to create Javascript Event Listener on post to page?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

What I want to do is to create an event listener for getting posted parameters to page. I want to use Javascript event listener. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry... I don't think the requirement is clear

Comment: Look into Ajax.  You can make a POST request to a page, and have listeners for certain responses.

Comment: Someone will post data to the page. And I will catch the posted parameters in event listener. How can I handle in pure javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

> client-side JavaScript does not allow access to POST/PUT/etc contents
>
> Servers don't generally send the request data back to the client.
>   What you are proposing would require the server to send the entire
>   request back every time. This doesn't seem reasonable. If you want the
>   client to have access to some data that originated on the client, why
>   does the server need to be involved at all?

here the reference http://lea.verou.me/2012/01/what-we-still-can%E2%80%99t-do-client-side/